# Auto Task Creation When Email Recieved In TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

I have my own TFS server plugin which sends me an email locally when any work item is assigned to me. Now, i have to do the following:

When I receive an email, then automatically a task will be created in project [name of my project] in TFS

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: this feels very cyclic, so someone makes a workitem, which sends you an email, which triggers the creation of another workitem? (which triggers an email...)  I think I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: when any work item is assign to me . them i recieved a mail.

Comment: now the scenario is when i received a mail. i.e (a bug has been assigned to you with id = (1) and title is (test) ) then tfs or my email or something else will create a task automatically for me!

Comment: but you already have a work item, why do you also need a task?

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you are trying to do. Give a specific example.

Comment: consider this........... when a bug is assign to me.......... i recieved a email alert ..... then what is my next step? i have to read the bug and resolve it. now if for the bug issue i have created a child task to resolve the bug .... in bug a new task is created (child task) i want my all developers to do that. so for this purpose i want that if any of the developer received a mail regarding bug. then automatically a child task is been created . i resolved a auto task created.

Comment: i have created a auto task creator but it is working directly when a bug is created then task is created . but i want that when email is received then task will be created automatically!!!!!

Comment: I don't see the difference, both end up sending the developer an email and creating a task for them. Is there a situation where the developer won't receive the email? Also why can't they just use the bug for tracking, what is the extra task actually adding?

Comment: betty . i have the scenerio .

Comment: that is when the subject of bug is "testing bug" then the task will be open. not on whole bug assignment . till now on every assignment the bug-task has been created! but i want only when the subject is "testing bug" then the bug child task will be open automaticalyy. but this is the later task. i think that i have use the pop3 for getting email . and then create a handler which check out the email  and its subject .